# Why isn't my background image showing?

Tags: html, css

I read another answer on here and fixed it (So I thought) but it still wont show up. I KNOW the image is background.jpg and it is in the img folder. I honestly am so confused why this isn't working. Could it be bootstrap messing with it? I assume not, because my custom CSS is after the bootstrap CSS.

```css
.main-section {
  background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BFG</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
      <ul class=" nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Hours</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gifts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Flowers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Balloons</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron main-section">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h1>Balloons Flowers and Gifts</h1>
        <h3>The perfect way to brighten someone's day, and make them smile!</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <a href="#"><h2>Balloons</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <a href="#"><h2>Flowers</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <a href="#"><h2>Gifts</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <a href="#"><h2>Hours</h2></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you check the console to see if the background image is not throwing any errors like File Not Found?

Comment: @praveenKumar No errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your imgfile, I just change your url of the firefox icon,it works.
chech if the file exist or right permission, and path.

```css
.main-section {
  background-image: url(http://newtab.firefoxchina.cn/img/worldindex/logo.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BFG</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
      <ul class=" nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Hours</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gifts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Flowers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Balloons</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron main-section">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h1>Balloons Flowers and Gifts</h1>
        <h3>The perfect way to brighten someone's day, and make them smile!</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <a href="#"><h2>Balloons</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <a href="#"><h2>Flowers</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <a href="#"><h2>Gifts</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <a href="#"><h2>Hours</h2></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I put the same CSS under the body selector and the image showed up. It must be something to do with main-section. I have no clue what it could be though.

Comment: @AustinMelms Have you had other styles, if yes, you css maybe overrided.

Comment: I have other styles in the CSS that work, it's just this.

Comment: @AustinMelms you have to find the css override by which, in the development console, by key F12.   And you have to google css override rules, and refer to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding background-size:cover; right after your background. Make sure you specify a width & height too for that section and you should be fine
Hope that helps :)

Comment: I tried that, and I put the same CSS under the body selector and the image showed up. It must be something to do with main-section. I have no clue what it could be though.